# Same matter in triplicate in a canvas

Tags: python, reportlab

```
c.setFont("Times-Roman", 12)    
c.drawRightString(148,750,"PARTICULARS")
c.drawRightString(148,475,"PARTICULARS")
c.drawRightString(148,200,"PARTICULARS")
```

Is there a way to shorten this code to achieve the same result?
(Python Reportlab pdf canvas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop.

```
c.setFont("Times-Roman", 12);
for y in range(750, 199, -275):
    c.drawRightString(148, y, "PARTICULARS")
```

Comment: Could you please explain the y values put forward by you?

Comment: It keeps subtracting 275 from 750 until it gets past 199.

Answer (score 1):

```
c.setFont("Times-Roman", 12)
for y_val in [750, 475, 200]:
    c.drawRightString(148,y_val,"PARTICULARS")
```

This is a general principle: put the fixed portions of your process into a small block of statements.  Put the variable parts into a sequence of some sort, and then iterate through that sequence.